# Excepted int for property "maxLength" of sap fiori Input component

Tags: sapui5

Current I am trying to metadata binding xml, [following this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/06/13/metadata-binding-in-ui5/). When I did the maxLength of Input. But I got the following error.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuPM0.png)

[demo service](http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata)

init model with destination:

```
initModel: function() {
    var sServiceUrl = "/odsrv/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/";
    var oModel = new OM(sServiceUrl, true);
    this.setModel(oModel, "oRefModel");
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "oRefModel");
}
```

xml view:

```
<content>
    <Label text="{oRefModel>/#Category/CategoryName/@type}"/>
    <Input maxLength="{oRefModel>/#Category/CategoryName/@maxLength}"/>
</content>
```

The Label for type works fine if remove Input.
How to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Input maxLength="{parts:[{path:'oRefModel>/#Category/CategoryName/@maxLength'}],formatter: 'your.formatter.toNum' }" />
```

> Formatter Code

```
toNum : function(maxlen){
            return parseInt(maxlen);;
        }
```

**Converting string to integer is the key**

Answer (score 1):

Version with expression binding could be like that

```
<Input maxLength="{= isNaN(${oRefModel>/#Category/CategoryName/@maxLength}) ? 0 : parseInt(${oRefModel>/#Category/CategoryName/@maxLength})" />
```

typeof check is needed cause at the start of binding process value of property probably is 'NaN' and it gives an error and whole process will stop.

If you can improve that version please do :)

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter and without writing a custom formatter function: Use the built-in parseInt function.

```
<Input
    maxLength="{
        path: 'oRefModel>/#Category/CategoryName/@maxLength',
        formatter: 'parseInt'
    }" />
```

---

For some reasons expression binding does **not** work, maybe someone could tell me why:

```
<Input maxLength="{= parseInt(${oRefModel>/#Category/CategoryName/@maxLength}) }" />
```